# Grid in eclipse background

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Is it possible (by plugin or anything) to make a grid in the eclipse code backround? I know one can make a margin, but havent seen any options for a grid.

Comment: What do you mean? Thin grey lines separating every single row and column in a text editor? Do you want this for some existing editor (e.g. Java) or for your own editor? And why?

Comment: I was wondering either it is possible for eclipse editor. Just a simple grid likr on a piece of paper- just a visual improvement eg. For each column and row like you said.

Comment: Eclipse has the ability to show whitespaces (find it in preferences). Maybe it does a part of what you're needing?